# Interpretability of feature weights from Gaussian process classifier

Tags: machine-learning, features

Suppose I trained a Gaussian process classifier with a linear kernel (using GPML toolbox) and got some feature weights for each input feature.

My question is then:

Does it/When does it make sense to interpret the weights to indicate the real-life importance of each feature or interpret at group level the average over the weights of a group of features?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.